# How to remove a website from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have access to a website's analytics from a former employer. The website is an internal tool that is not available in a public kinda way. I would like to delete this website/profile from my analytics account. I've searched through the documentation for analytics but it seems like it's a little out of date. Does anyone have the low-down on how to do this?

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "delete" the profile **only for your** account, ask to the profile's Administrator to delete you from the users list.

Answer (score 0):

Google now has a method for removing an account (web site) from your administration list WITHOUT deleting the GA account that other users may be relying on.

From the GA Admin screen, select the account you wish to remove. In the first column (Account) select USER MANAGEMENT -> Remove myself from this account.