# How to remove a web site from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am Administrator of several web sites on google analytics.

Can i delete some of them?

If yes, how?

Many of you suggested me to remove my profile. So my doubts are:
1. I am administrator of several items. I want remove just some of them.
2. If I remove my profile I will lost all items?

[image]

Comment: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009698

Comment: @PranavKapoor, I don't want to Add/modify/delete account administrators. I just want to remove a web site from google analytics. I uploaded a picture to make me more clear.

Comment: I did GA consulting and had a similar situation when other admins made me an admin. I couldn't delete the account from my list. I had to contact them to remove me as an admin on their account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a website from Google Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303991/how-to-remove-a-website-from-google-analytics)

Answer (score 165):

Here's an updated answer, as of Sept. 2013. This took me awhile to figure out.

1. Go to the Admin tab.

   > [image]
2. In the middle column, select the web property that you want to delete from the dropdown.

   > [image]
3. In the right-hand column, click on "View Settings." ("Property Settings" in dec. 2015)

   > [image]
4. At the bottom of the next page, select "Delete this view."

   > [image]

It will warn you that you're about to delete all of the data associated with this property. If you're sure, confirm.

Done!

Comment: +1 for pictures. It's hard to understand this just by looking at text directions.

Comment: Intuitive it ain't ;-)

Comment: @DilbertDave: +1 it's as intuitive as most of Google apps. :-)

Comment: They change the options all the time. Now, it has rubbish bin option.

Comment: these days its called rubbish bin for deletion :)

Answer (score 68):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Google Analytics Admin panel has **3 panels**, wherein deleting can be done on any of the following :

1. **Account** (Contains multiple properties, and views)
2. **Properties** (Contains Views, a subset of Account)
3. **Views** (subset of properties)

[image: Google Analytics Admin Panel]

---

### Deleting an Account

Deleting the account, will **remove all data** pertaining to that account, along with **all properties/profiles** it contains. This is (usually) as good as removing the entire website data.

To delete the account, follow the following steps : (refer to image below)

- Choose the account you want to delete.

[image: Choose the account you want to delete]

- Click on Account Settings

[image: Click Account Settings]

- Bottom right, a small link that says delete this account.

[image: Delete account]

- You will get a confirmation, if you are sure to, click `Delete Account`
- It will give you details, and will confirm deletion (and provide additional info like to remove GA snippet on your website, etc)

Note : If you have multiple accounts linked with your login, the other accounts are NOT touched, *only this account will be deleted*.

---

### Deleting a property

Deleting a property will remove the selected property, and all the views it holds.
To delete a property, delete all views it contains individually (see below for deleting views)

- Choose the property

[image: Property choice]

- All profiles related to that property appear on the right
- Delete all the views related to the property individually (details in next section).

---

### Deleting a View (profile)

Deleting a profile will remove only data *pertaining to that view*, if there is a single profile, the property is automatically deleted.

- Choose the profile you want to delete

[image: Choose profile]

- Click View Settings

[image: Settings]

- Click on delete View (Bottom right)

[image: Delete the view]

- Click Confirm, and that view will be deleted. If there is only a single view in the property, that property gets automatically deleted.

---

### I want to keep the data, but not see them in the list

Sometimes you have a lot of websites, which you want to keep the data, but remove them from the list, since you don't view them often. I thought of a workaround, in case you do not want to delete the data.

Use another account.

1. Say, your primary account is **A**, and you make another account **B**.
2. Make **B** an administrator from **A**
3. Remove **A**

Since **A** was your primary account, you no longer will be able to access it from the list!
And you still have your data saved, just that you'll have to log in via the other (spare) account.

---

Previous Answer :

These are the steps to delete a profile from [Google Support page](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009621) :

> Delete profiles
>
> Remember, too, that when you delete a profile, you also delete all data associated with that profile, and it is not possible to retrieve that deleted data.
>
> To delete a profile:
>
> 1. Click the Admin tab at the top right of any Analytics page.
> 2. Click the account that contains the profile you want to delete.
> 3. Click the web property from which you want to delete the profile.
> 4. Use the Profile menu to select the profile.
> 5. Click the Profile Settings tab.
> 6. Click Delete this profile at the bottom of the page.
> 7. Click Delete in the confirmation message.

Comment: I don't want to delete an account administrator. I just want to delete a site from the list.

Comment: @LorraineBernard : You can remove a either remove a profile, or a user from an analytics account. You **cannot** remove items from the list without removing yourself from that account/profile.

Comment: The issue is 1) I am administrator of several items. I want remove just some of them. 2) If I remove my profile I will lost all items?

Comment: Profiles have been renamed to 'views' - please update the answer.

Answer (score 21):

### Updated Answer (July 22, 2015)

The solution to delete an Account/Property/View is still very similar to @Pranav 웃's answer. Google has just moved a few things around, so I thought I would update.

### Step #1

Click Admin Tab at the top of the page

[image: Step #1]

### Step #2

Once you are on the Admin Page, You need to decide if you want to delete the Account, Property, or View. Make sure to select the desired Account, Property, or View from the Drop Down Menu.

In the following pictures, I will show you how to delete the Account, which removes all information including Properties and Views under that particular account.

Click Account Settings to remove Account, Property Settings to remove Property, and View Settings to remove View.

[image: Step #2]

### Step #3

On Account Settings, you will notice a button 'Move to Trash Can'. You will click this to remove the Account, Property or View. You will have to verify Moving the Account to the Trash Can on the next page/picture.

[image: Step #3]

### Step #4

When you have verified this is the account you want to delete, go ahead and select 'Trash Account'.

Note: When you Trash an Account it moves all the information to Admin/Account/Trash Can, where it can be recovered within 1 month. Keep in mind that every Account has its own Trash Can. Once that time has lapsed the Account, Property or View will be deleted FOREVER!

[image: Step #4]

Hope this helps someone in the future, since I just struggled trying to figure it out even though its pretty simple now.

Comment: Additional Note: Permenant deletion takes 35 days. Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009696?hl=en

Answer (score 7):

> To delete a web property, you simply need to delete every profile within the property.  Once the last profile has been deleted, the web property with cease to exist in the GA account.  That's all there is to it! -- [Source](http://fitandfinish.ironworks.com/2012/08/google-analytics-tip-how-to-delete-profiles-and-web-properties.html)

Answer (score 5):

After Much Fannying about, deleting this that etc, I found the way to delete a "website" from your list (which is, in fact what the original question was - minus all the flaffing) is

- Select the Account (Website) that you want to delete
- In the first column (left hand one)
- Click Account Settings
- Down the bottom, it says Delete this account.

That's it… Done.

Remember: for this exercise only Account means Website.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do in this way :
select your profile then go to admin => in admin second column "Property" select the site you want to remove => go to third column "view settings" clic => on the right bottom you ll see delete the view => confirm and it s done , have a nice day all

Answer (score 2):

Feb 2016 version: Admin tab, then select Property in the middle column, click Property Settings, then the Move To Trash Can button at the top right. No need to delete individual views.

Answer (score 2):

Update 26/03/2016:

Instead of a link in the bottom right corner of the Settings form, the delete button is moved to the top right corner, saying:

```
Move To Trash Can
```

When you click on it, it will ask you for confirmation and move it to `Trash Can`.

Comment: In some cases the button reads 'Move to rubbish bin' instead.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP wants to do, is delete additional properties in his Google analytics.
Properties that are not his but belong to someone else.

Apparently, the only way to do this, is to contact the owner of that website who is the administrator, and asked them to remove you.

Or you can just create a new Google account, and add your properties to the new account.

None of these are real good solutions. Thank you Google for caring so much about SEO people.

To add insult to injury, if you go over 25 accounts, you must contact Google to get permission to add another.

Lesson learned: Do not add other peoples websites to your Google analytics account. Create a separate account so that if you have to start over, you don't lose any data from your websites. It's also good to have more than one Google analytics account.

Answer (score 0):

AS of 2018

```
Login to your analytics account
Select the account/property you want to delete
Click the  button. (left side bottom menu)
Click on property settings
To the right you will see Move To Trash Can Click on that
You will see the bellow screen. click on Delete Property button
```

or if you want to delete the account

follow the same steps, but this time click on the Accoutn Settings tab  see below

Now Click on Move to Trash Can (button to the right)

when you see the next screen confirm to delete the account by clicking on the Trash Account button.

[How to delete a website from google analytics](https://scloudes.com/learning/how-to-delete-a-website-from-google-analytics/)