# See how the website is visited (mouse movements DOM)

Tags: google-analytics

[Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) has a great feature that allows to see how a visitor visited your website, you can "replay" his visit, and see how the DOM of the website was visited, see the mouse movements, the page scrolls. This is an [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7lAeFRNJA8) video.

**Is this feature available in Google Analytics?** If so, where? I haven't found it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a consumer product.

Comment: @SLaks why the tag `google-analytics` then?

Comment: For questions about their API.

Comment: @SLaks I just checked, and at least 50% of the 10 highest-voted questions of the tag `google-analytics` are not about API, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125568/how-to-remove-a-web-site-from-google-analytics so...